# Activity's local variable still valid after OnDestroy()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ondestroy

I have declared a class for doing work in the background:

```
public class ReportLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void, ReportLoadTaskResult> {

    public ReportLoadTask(Context context, String barcode, ReportLoadTaskListener l) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I am using an instance of this class as an `Activity`'s local variable:

```
private ReportLoadTask mReportLoadTask;

...
```

in one point of class' code I am preparing a task and then letting user decide whether to continue or not by showing `AlertDialog`:

```
mReportLoadTask = new ReportLoadTask(this, barcode, this)

...

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Continue with search?" )
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mReportLoadTask.execute();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        mReportLoadTask = null;
                        return;
                    }
                })
                .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .show();
```

When testing I was expecting `mReportLoadTask` to become `null` if I destroy `Activity` (for example by rotating the device) while `AlertDialog` is being shown. But in practice this doesn't happen. All the `Activity` lifecycle methods (`OnPause`, `OnStop`, `OnDestroy`) are being called correctly, even other local variables (some `int`s) are destroyed but this variable somehow seems to "survive". Why is that?

After exploring the Net it seems like Android is keeping a reference of this object somewhere but where could it keep it? The only reference to this object is in my `Activity` and it is being destroyed.

Comment: Probably `mReportLoadTask` is running have you tried it after calling `mReportLoadTask.cancel` before making `mReportLoadTask` object null ?

Comment: `mReportLoadTask` will only become `null` if you explicitly set `null` to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are rotating the device while dialog is being show, it means that your task is not executed (you haven't called `execute` yet). When you rotate the device, your activity is destroyed and **recreated** (it will be started from the scratch and *life cycle callbacks will be called again*).

When activity is recreated `mReportLoadTask = new ReportLoadTask(this, barcode, this)` is called again and your are getting a `new instance`.

Comment: Yes, that was the case. Should have examined the workflow a bit more.